# Passing boolean parameters to spring JPA for postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I have following  JPA query

```
SELECT t
FROM Ticket t, Employee e
WHERE t.employee.empId=e.empId AND t.employee.active=TRUE
```

The Boolean parameter `active` seems not working.

database - postgres, boolean type
java type in entity class - primitive boolean

Any possible reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean under `seems not working`? What is the generated sql?

Comment: Can you share entity design?